# Block page rendering for @import CSS

Tags: css, blocking, css-import

TLDR; skip to the *problem* section

**Background**

We have a very large monolith legacy application. We are in the process of stripping functionality out into a new application.

These two applications have vastly different UI's built in vastly different architectures and technologies. As our users will be navigating freely between the two, currently, we need to unify the UI to some degree so the transition isn't so jarring.

It was decided to have a large CSS override style-sheet that we just load over the top of the legacy application (So we could spend more time focusing on the new app). This sheet, whilst massive, works.

Our legacy app has a root CSS file that is included on every page, regardless of how (some is classic ASP, some uses master pages, some is manually).

**The problem**

So we decided to use a @import tag in the root style sheet to pull in our re-style override.

Whilst we acknowledge that blocking rendering of the page is a horrible anti pattern we need this behavior to prevent flashing of the old UI, until the override sheet takes over.

We thought that CSS in the head will block rendering of the page until its loaded, however it doesn't appear to be waiting for the imported CSS. Is this expected behavior with regards to imports? Is there any way to make the user agent wait? Any information how how to achieve this would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you _want_ to block rendering until the "re-style override" css file has been loaded, is that correct?

Comment: The thing that's interesting is that in order for `@import` to work, it has to be at the top of the css file and therefore come first in the waterfall. However you are using for overrides. Is that actually working?

Comment: @JakeParis `@import` sheets might be above in the waterfall but CSS it constantly new rendered with every asynchronously loaded stylesheet. To wait or not wait for re-render is a browser decision and cannot be turned off or synchronized. You can only load and apply them at the same time or in a wanted order by loading them with JS (e.g. XHR) which I would not recommend for basic style sheets.

Comment: @JakeParis Don't forget about the greatest bodge tool ever: `!important` – But I get your point. @ste2425, are you sure it is caused by the asynchronous loading of the CSS? Or is a class applied later via JS that you use in the new style, or something like that

Comment: @JakeParis & Niklas yup we would like to block rendering until the imported override sheet has been loaded so that when the page is rendered the new UI is rendered instantly.

Sadly no Js classes or anything like getting involved, checked that side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to apply another CSS file synchronously to the CSS file it is embedded in. But as you already doing a lot of [bodging](https://youtu.be/lIFE7h3m40U?t=19) in this project, here are some suggestions I can make:

*(But before that: All of those aren't really good, not to say best-practice, and have definitely some danger to it.)*

1. **Hide the GUI in the critical section:** Add a CSS rule in the root stylesheet, that hides the GUI, and another in the new stylesheet that overrides it and shows the GUI again.
2. **If you can add something to all HTML pages:** Add a loading screen. Something like
   `<div class="loading-screen" style="display:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100vw;height:100vh;background-color:white;z-index:1000">Loading...</div>`
   and hide it again with the new sytylesheet: `.loading-screen { display: none; }`
3. **All in one:** Throw away the idea of using `@import` and write the content of your new stylesheet in the root stylesheet.

The best practice would probably be to rework the hole site structure or at least rework/remove the old GUI style.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The legacy application is huge, it will be a number of years until the functionality has been replaced within new applications. Re-working the structure or changing the root CSS, sadly, isn't an option. Plus it would be somewhat a waste of time as the old code base just isn't salvageable. That make options 2 un-feasible due to the huge amount of changes needed. The re-style needs to be toggle-able making option 3 difficult also.
However Option 1 could be onto something. I will investigate and get back to you.